# Class constructor SomeClass cannot be invoked without 'new' however SomeClass is an Abstract Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, abstract-class

I am using typescript, gulp build and node.

pre-information:
I have an abstract class say SomeClass and A and B are derived classes of that abstract class i.e. SomeClass. The code wants to create an instance of the derived class by passing constructor function that returns an instance of Type T.

This is the Relevant information about that function definition

```
**async getInstances<T extends SomeClass>(typedConstructor: new () => T): Promise<T>
{
return new typedConstructor();
}**
```

let say I call this function by passing A that is a derived class of that Abstract class i.e. some class.

getInstance(A);

Post Information:

Now after building this code using gulp when I execute it using node this class is supposed to give me an instance of class A. However, it throws an error saying:

**Class constructor SomeClass cannot be invoked without new**

What grinds my gears is that SomeClass is an Abstract class then why the error is saying to use New for that class.

Comment: There might be something else going on, best I can tell this should have reproduced the error, but it works fine: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=async%20function%20getInstances%3CT%20extends%20SomeClass%3E(typedConstructor%3A%20new%20()%20%3D%3E%20T)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20typedConstructor()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20SomeClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20SomeClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AgetInstances(Derived)%3B%0D%0A

Comment: Where and how `A` is declared?

Comment: Second @Titian, it should work. I do this everyday.

Comment: @unional Yup that was my point, I tried to reproduce the problem according to the description and I found no problem, everything works.